# Ongoing work - Powershell Script For Creating Multiple Mailboxes From CSV - With some additional Features

Tags: powershell

I am currently working on a script that should do the following features:

1. Create New-mailboxes, according to CSV File, Which is currently set-up like this:

[image: CSV/Excel file screenshot]

The script i am using, is as follows.

```bsh
#. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
#Connect-ExchangeServer -auto


<#
 # Bulk Mailbox creation for Exchange.
 Will create Mailbox's & AD Users.
 CSV / script can be expanded to create more attributes.

Steve Lindsey
11/11/2013

#>
#csv format needs to be as follows: 
#Alias,Firstname, Lastname,Name,UPN,OUpath,MBDB,password
#change the name and path of the csv file as required.

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-CSV C:\Users\user\Desktop\PowerShell\mailboxes2.csv  
$users| foreach {

$Password = convertto-securestring $_.password -asplaintext -force 
new-mailbox -name $_.name -alias $_.alias -displayname $_.Displayname -FirstName $_.Firstname -LastName $_.Lastname -userPrincipalName $_.userPrincipalName -PrimarySmtpAddress $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -Database $_.database -RetentionPolicy "b3a83dc4-e471-4d05-b357-25535aa027af" -OrganizationalUnit $_.OrganizationalUnit -Password $Password –ResetPasswordOnNextLogon:$false
}
sleep 30

foreach($user in $users){set-mailbox $user.alias -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true}

sleep 30

foreach($user in $users){set-mailbox $user.alias -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$false}

sleep 30

foreach($user in $users){set-mailbox $user.PrimarySmtpAddress -PrimarySmtpAddress $user.PrimarySmtpAddress}
foreach($user in $users){Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($user.userprincipalname)'" | Set-ADUser -PostalCode "0101010101" -POBox "000"}
```

In addition to what this script initialy does,
I need it to also be able to do following, after creating the mailboxes.

1. each of the Active Directory -  USER objects , created for each mailbox should contain, ZIP \ PostalCode "01010101" -POBox "000" + Description "INC000002507906". and created  under
   The address tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZtbU.jpg

For the "description" part i would look to set some additional column if possible in the imported CSV. so i can edit it, and each time the script will pick up the text from there.

I have tried the following , to achieve these, at the end of the script.

```
# foreach($user in $users){Set-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userprincipalname)'" -PostalCode "0101010101" -POBox "000"}
# foreach($user in $users){Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userprincipalname)'" | Set-ADUser -PostalCode "0101010101" -POBox "000"}
# foreach($user in $users){Get-ADUser $user.identity | Set-ADUser -PostalCode "0101010101" -POBox "000"}
# foreach($user in $users){Get-ADUser $users |Set-ADUser -PostalCode "0101010101" -POBox  "000"}
# Foreach($user in $users){Set-ADUser -Identity $users -PostalCode "01010101" -POBox "000"}
```

Each time i tried these, i faced with a filter error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ghz.jpg

2. The second thing i need to do , is to force the script to go over the CSV
   Again, and set the default SMTP , for each user/mailbox created, as set in
   the "PrimarySmtpAddres" column.
   This is due, to when the  EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true cmdlet takes
   takes place in the code, it sets the Primary Smtp back to the
   organization`s default one.

   I researched this a bit online and from what i could gather, this might be accomplished with something like :

   Set-mailbox somealias -PrimarySmtpAddress "some.guy@contoso.com"

Combined with for each command, i believe it might work, i am m just not sure of the syntax i should use to accomplish that.

Your help is greatly appreciated

<<< UPDATE >>>

With help from AdminOFThings - most have been accomplished.
Thank you very much sir.

Now , all i have left needed , is the following:

foreach($user in $users){Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($user.userprincipalname)'" | Set-ADUser -PostalCode "0101010101" -POBox "000"}

This is, the last "foreach" i have in the script.
i want also, in addition to add " -Description " to the parameters of the Set-ADuser cmdlet. in addition i would like to add, another column to the CSV file,
which will be title "Description" and for each line\mailbox created , a different description will be put in. the script will run and add the description defined on each mailbox in the file, on the description colum\line.
Please assist accomplishing that.

Comment: Since you are using a `foreach` loop rather than a `foreach-object`, pipeline variable `$_` does not contain what you expect. Your current object is now `$user`. You need to update your filters to be like `"UserPrincipalName -eq '$($user.userprincipalname)'"`. `Get-ADUser $user.identity` is syntactically correct, but I don't see an identity column in your CSV. So that will fail as a result.

Comment: Thanks, i have apllied what you said and all works great. i am going to post another Please see the edits i have done for my post, i would like some further assistance with the CSV / and adding description from the description column.

Comment: Any thoughts, regarding my last comment here? still looking for help on adding description to each user created along with the mailboxes. everyone`s help is  greatly appreciated, thank you.